# MySQL select rows from left join with specific number of distinct values in one column but without total row limit

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 2 tables (records, features) that are connected by one foreign key-relationship.

Now I want to draw samples from those two tables where in my primary table
I select by an id which is the primary key.

So if I wanted to get all entries it would look like this:

```
SELECT features.record_id, [...more columns...]
FROM records 
LEFT JOIN features ON records.id = features.record_id
ORDER BY records.id
```

What I try to achieve:

I would like to enhance the query so I can specify an exact number **n** of distinct values of *records.record_id*. I don't want **n** rows but all rows from the join until I have **n** diffferent *record_id*s without limiting the total number of rows in the most efficient way. I hope this is understandable, if not: please tell me and I will try to elaborate my question.

To add additinal context:

I use this inside a java-program (plain jdbc) and my goal is to collect the information to build **n** fully populated record-objects in the most efficient way. I already tried drawing all data and iterate over the ordered result until I constructed a sufficient number of record-objects but it didn't turn out very efficient (already takes about half a minute for 100k entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of rows from `records` with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT features.* FROM (
  SELECT records.record_id 
  FROM records LIMIT 100
) t
LEFT JOIN features ON t.record_id = features.record_id
ORDER BY t.record_id
```

the column `record_id` is the primary key so you don't need `distinct`.

Comment: Nice! I didn't now you can nest SELECTs, but it's logical if I think about it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is by the way about 5 times faster on my machine than only drawing n records from the record table and starting a select individually for every record. It runs out of heap-space for 1M records (which means around 10M rows total) but I will try to solve that with batchification.